# Getting circular object in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a big array of objects, in which I have to use two particular object keys for each element custom_attributes and  custom_options. For each attribute one flavor from custom_options will be added and price will be noted. So if we have 3 attributes and 7 flavours we will get an array of length 7 with every attributes and 1 flavor in each element with different prices.

```
     "custom_attributes": [
                        {
                            "attribute_code": "shape",
                            "value": "Round"
                        },
                        {
                            "attribute_code": "weight",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "attribute_code": "product_type",
                            "value": "NEG"
                        }
                    ],
   "custom_options": [
                        {
                            "attribute_code": "flavor",
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "additional_price": 0,
                                    "slug": "vanilla",
                                    "label": "Vanilla",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "24",
                                    "additional_price": 100,
                                    "slug": "pineapple-vanilla",
                                    "label": "Pineapple Vanilla",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "2",
                                    "additional_price": 100,
                                    "slug": "butterscotch",
                                    "label": "Butterscotch",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "10",
                                    "additional_price": 100,
                                    "slug": "black-forest",
                                    "label": "Black Forest",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "20",
                                    "additional_price": 200,
                                    "slug": "chocolate-truffle",
                                    "label": "Chocolate Truffle",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "5",
                                    "additional_price": 150,
                                    "slug": "blueberry",
                                    "label": "Blueberry",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "4",
                                    "additional_price": 150,
                                    "slug": "strawberry",
                                    "label": "Strawberry",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "13",
                                    "additional_price": 200,
                                    "slug": "red-velvet",
                                    "label": "Red Velvet",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "23",
                                    "additional_price": 150,
                                    "slug": "white-forest",
                                    "label": "White Forest",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "6",
                                    "additional_price": 200,
                                    "slug": "mixed-fruit",
                                    "label": "Mixed Fruit",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "9",
                                    "additional_price": 150,
                                    "slug": "mango",
                                    "label": "Mango",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1615798387075",
                                    "additional_price": 200,
                                    "slug": "irish_coffee",
                                    "label": "Irish Coffee",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1615798423428",
                                    "additional_price": 300,
                                    "slug": "death_by_chocolate",
                                    "label": "Death By Chocolate",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1615798462183",
                                    "additional_price": 250,
                                    "slug": "vancho",
                                    "label": "Vancho",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1615287938626",
                                    "additional_price": 230,
                                    "slug": "gulab_jamun_vanilla",
                                    "label": "Gulab Jamun Vanilla",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "1615287902661",
                                    "additional_price": 250,
                                    "slug": "gulab_jamun_red_velvet",
                                    "label": "Gulab Jamun Red Velvet",
                                    "image": null
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "26",
                                    "additional_price": 350,
                                    "slug": "rasmalai",
                                    "label": "Rasmalai",
                                    "image": null
                                }
                            ],
                            "min_select": 1,
                            "max_select": 1
                        }
                    ],
```

The code below is what I'm using now but the end result I get is a circular object.

```
const variants = configurable_children.map(variant => {
     const vop = variant.custom_attributes.map(k => {
            if(k.attribute_code === "weight")
            {
            const weight_value = (attributes[attributes.findIndex(el => el.slug === k.attribute_code)].options[k.value].slug);
                return ({
                    'name': k.attribute_code,
                    "value": weight_value
                })
            }
             else if(k.attribute_code === "shape"){
             const shape_value = (attributes[attributes.findIndex(el => el.slug === k.attribute_code)].options[k.value].slug);
                return ({
                    'name': k.attribute_code,
                    "value": shape_value
                })
            }
             else if(k.attribute_code === "product_type"){
                return ({
                    'name': k.attribute_code,
                    "value": k.value === "EG" ? "egg" : "eggless"
                })
            }
 });
                if(variant.custom_options.length === 0){
            return ({
                'price': variant.discount_price,
                'compare_price': variant.final_price,
                'sku': variant.sku,
                "options": vop
            })
                    }else{
            //map over all custom_fields as well
            let options = variant.custom_options[0].values.map(op => {
                                                return ({
                                         'price': variant.discount_price + op.additional_price,
                                         'compare_price': variant.final_price +op.additional_price,
                                         'sku': variant.sku,
                                         "options":  [ ...vop,{name: variant.custom_options[0].attribute_code, value: op.slug }]
                                     })
            });
            console.log("options flavour: -------------");
            console.log(options);
            return options
                    } 
   
});
```

The issue is happening in the last return statement of last else statement where I'm spreading the the vop array I got before to all the new mapped values and returning. I'm getting circular object error.

Should I change my approach or Am I missing something here ?

Comment: That data array is unusual. Less is more, keep it simple. Not sure why _custom_attributes_ is separate from _custom_options_   And embedded _.map()_ functions?  Ugh. Keep it simple.

Comment: Yeah the schema sucked, and now we have to migratevso all this pain. Is embedded map() not good ? What's the alternative?

Comment: I can create functions to keep it simple, but that's not the issue here